# how to find a better bayesian networks structure for large-scale dataset

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, bayesian-network

The data set we hold is related to the after-sales service of a factory, which has about one million records, 8 variables, and a large number of different modes in these variables, (for example, one of the variables has about 8000 different modes.  1. If we want to perform the Bayesian network, which algorithm is suitable and optimal for determining the structure learning? 2. Once we have chosen the algorithm, how do we know that the model predicts correctly?

Comment: I'd try a shot with the package BDgraph in R

Comment: @mariob6 do you know any lib in python ?